# List files details from folders and subfolders are duplicading

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the names of the files within the directory and the sub directories within the "parent" directory.

I managed to solve my problem in parts, but in the last directory it is multiplying the files (as if I was checking this folder twice).
If I have 2 items, he is exporting me 4 to that last directory.

I managed to get the files from the directories, but if I have any files in the root directory (parent directory), it won't list.

> Parent dir "\XML"
>
> - File1.xlsx
> - File2.txt
> - Folder2
>
> Dir "Folder2"
>
> - File1.xml
> - File2.xml

**So, in the CSV file exported will be 4 rows, which is duplicate files from "Folder2" folder. And it won't bring me the files in the "XML" folder, which is the parent folder.**

Powershell script:

```
# To execute the script without agreeing with the execution policy
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process

# Defines the parent directory, where all files and folders inside it will be
$DirPai = 'D:\Users\F02579\Desktop\XML'

# Variable to store all directories within the parent directory
$DirPastas = (Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse $DirPai).FullName

# Variable that will keep the final result
$results = @()

foreach ($Dir in $DirPastas)
{
    # Write the directory name
    Write-Host $Dir
    # Get the file details
    $Arquivos = Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir -Recurse | Select-Object Directory, Name, Lenght, LastWriteTime, @{Name="Extension";Expression={$_.Extension}} #| Where-Object "Extension"-ne ''
    # Store the result for each path
    $results += $Arquivos
}

# Defines the directory to which the final file will be exported
$DiretorioExportacao = 'D:\Users\F02579\Desktop\XML\I_PI_LISTFILES.csv'

# Export the result to CSV in the previously informed directory
$results | Export-Csv -Path $DiretorioExportacao -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce your code to the following.

1. Keep only the first Get_ChildItem.  Remove the -Dir switch (ie. get files and folders)
2. Pipe directly to Select-Object. Don't bother with an explicit loop.

This will give a result with five items: four files and one folder.

You also had a typo with 'length'.

Cheers.

```
# To execute the script without agreeing with the execution policy
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process

# Defines the parent directory, where all files and folders inside it will be
$DirPai = 'D:\Users\F02579\Desktop\XML'

$results = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse $DirPai) | Select-Object Directory, Name, Length, LastWriteTime, @{Name="Extension";Expression={$_.Extension}} #| Where-Object "Extension"-ne ''

# Defines the directory to which the final file will be exported
$DiretorioExportacao = 'D:\Users\F02579\Desktop\XML\I_PI_LISTFILES.csv'

# Export the result to CSV in the previously informed directory
$results | Export-Csv -Path $DiretorioExportacao -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I's faster and even cleaner. Why type 'length' was not coming with data before? What was wrong?

Comment: In your code, you had "lenght".  Correct spelling is "length".  

Answer (score 0):

You already have all the directories captured so in your loop you need to specify the -File parameter and there is no need for the -Recurse parmaeter.

```
   $Arquivos = Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir -File | 
            Select-Object @{Name="Directory",Expression($Dir),
                    Name, Lenght, LastWriteTime, 
                    @{Name="Extension";Expression={$_.Extension}}
```

HTH